# Proper repeat statement for PROC genmod

Tags: sas

*I think the question is more related to SAS syntax than statistics and is about proper repeated statement for PROC genmod*

I am trying to implement  Poisson regression with log link and with robust error variance for survey data.

Here is a working code for **non survey** data that I tested and it works as intended:

```
proc genmod data = eyestudy;
 class carrot id;
 model lenses = carrot/ dist = poisson link = log;
 repeated subject = id/ type = unstr;
 estimate 'Beta' carrot 1 -1/ exp;
run;
```

Code above and more information about Poisson regression with log link and with robust error variance but fro non survey data is here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-estimate-relative-risk-in-sas-using-proc-genmod-for-common-outcomes-in-cohort-studies/

Below is an example how to use code for `PROC genmod` for survey analysis (but with `dist=binomial link=identity` and I think without robust error variance)

```
proc genmod data=nis10;
class seqnumt estiapt10;
model r_tet_not_utd = / dist=binomial link=identity;
weight provwt;
repeated subject=seqnumt(estiapt10);
where sex = 2;
run;
```

here strata variable name is `estiapt10`, cluster variable name is `seqnumt` and weight variable name is `provwt`.

Code above and more information about survey data analysis here: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/272-2013.pdf

My strata variable name is `CSTRATM`, cluster variable name is `CPSUM` and weight variable name is `PATWT`. Dependent variable name is `DIETNUTR` independent variable name is `age_group_var`. My data is located in `sas_stata`. So I tryed this code:

```
proc genmod data=sas_stata;
class age_group_var id CPSUM CSTRATM;
model DIETNUTR = age_group_var/ dist = poisson link = log;
weight PATWT;
repeated subject = id/ type = unstr;
repeated subject = CPSUM(CSTRATM);
estimate 'Beta' age_group_var 1 -1/ exp;
run;
```

but it gave me warning:

```
WARNING: Only the last REPEATED statement is used.
```

As I understand after reading articles above and some other material I am doing everything right except not the proper `repeated` statement. For Poisson regression with log link and with robust error variance for survey data I assume there should be some combination of two `repeated` statements in my code above. I tried several variants of combining those `repeated` statements but without any luck.

**So my question is:** What is the code for Poisson regression with log link and with robust error variance for survey data?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understood what `CPSUM(CSTRATM)` is. But I am assuming you are looking to use a interactive or nested effect as the subject.

Assuming `x = CPSUM(CSTRATM)`, you could code up the effect as:

```
repeated subject = id * x
```

A full survey of coding up effects can be found at

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_genmod_sect038.htm

This might be a useful read also:
https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi29/188-29.pdf

Comment: When using https://pastebin.com/YcK07PpR got the error: https://pastebin.com/uaXDVMSC  In `CPSUM(CSTRATM)` `CPSUM` is claster variable and `CSTRATM` is strata variable. I got this combination from this paper: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/272-2013.pdf from the page 5 (they use same combination but different variable names `seqnumt(estiapt10)` with `repeated` statement) and on the page 2 you can see that `estiapt10` is strata variable and `seqnumt` is cluster variable.

Comment: Apologies - I misread your inputs and responded obliquely. Deleted the original comment to avoid confusion. CPSUM(CSTRATM) is actually a nested effect. You could try something like `repeated subject = id * CPSUM(CSTRATM)`. But try to understand the different effects in the link I posted above and make sure this is actually what you want - only you can be judge of it